# Start a program from System32 in C++ Builder 11

Tags: touch, c++builder, calibration

I want to launch the touchpanel calibration program from within my application I'm developing. I am able to launch **MultiDigiMon** from regular cmd but I can't get it to work in the elevated Embarcadero IDE using
`system("start C:\\Windows\\System32\\MultiDigiMon.exe -touch");`
command.

Any ideas what may be the cause of this problem?

Comment: `system` is not how you start a process in Windows. Read about [`CreateProcessA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) instead.

Comment: I made a project in VisualStudio to explore the error more thoroughly and I tried other functions among which there was CreateProcess. The problem I encountered there was that the app seemed to work (exited with code 0) but no other window appeared.

Comment: Were you running VS elevated when the app "worked"? Maybe related: [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131118-00/?p=2643) and [redux](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190425-00/?p=102443)